# Why does this MSDN example for Func<> delegate have a superfluous Select() call?

Tags: c#, delegates, msdn

The MSDN gives this code example in the article on the [Func Generic Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28FUNC%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true):

```
Func<String, int, bool> predicate = ( str, index) => str.Length == index;

String[] words = { "orange", "apple", "Article", "elephant", "star", "and" };
IEnumerable<String> aWords = words.Where(predicate).Select(str => str);

foreach (String word in aWords)
    Console.WriteLine(word);
```

I understand what all this is doing. What I don't understand is the

```
Select(str => str)
```

bit. Surely that's not needed? If you leave it out and just have

```
IEnumerable<String> aWords = words.Where(predicate);
```

then you still get an IEnumerable back that contains the same results, and the code prints the same thing.

Am I missing something, or is the example misleading?

Comment: The example I see has `Func<String, String> predicate = str => str.ToUpper()` and no such `Select`.

Comment: I see it as shown in question above

Comment: @zneak - what language do you have selected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Select` is indeed redundant.

I suspect that this example may have been "translated" from the query comprehension syntax, as in:

```
IEnumerable<String> aWords = 
    from w in words
    where (...)
    select w;
```

When using this syntax, you *have* to `select` at the end, it's just how the compiler works.  When using the `Where` extension method, however, it's completely unnecessary unless you actually need to do a separate projection.

Or, maybe it's just a mistake.  The MSDN writers aren't infallible!

Comment: does this mean the lambda syntax is more efficient?

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet: They're identical, just different ways of writing the same query.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not needed.

Such a construct could be used if you wanted to force a sequence to be lazily evaluated i.e. to prevent casting. If you had a method that returned a `List<T>` but declared an `IEnumerable<T>` return type then a client could cast the return type and manipulate the underlying list directly. Obviously this is a very bad idea, but a class could protect its state by applying an identity select such as the one used in this example:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Items
{
   get { return privateList.Select(i => i); }
}
```

Comment: In such cases, I would "return privateList.AsReadOnly();" instead, even if returning IEnumerable<T>.
ReadOnlyCollection has the advantage that it implements ICollection, which makes some LINQ operators (such as ToArray()) faster because the collection length is known.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it's not needed, there's a feedback button on bottom of [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28FUNC%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true).  Tell them the .Select is not needed.  The mere fact that the Select clause is just:

```
Select(str => str)
```

It receives string and outputs the **same** string

Answer (score 0):

You have a very strange link there. This topic is not in TOC, and it has the following at the top:

*"[This topic is pre-release documentation and is subject to change in future releases. Blank topics are included as placeholders.]"*

The first line also looks like writer's comment to himself/herself.

And since VS 2010 and .NET 4.0 just released, I guess, this is some kind of broken topic that hasn't been deleted/replaced in time.

I think, the correct URL now for this content is this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534303.aspx

By the way, how did you get your URL? Was it through MSDN search or something else?